# Mob Health Check

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

My question is as simple as it sounds; is there a way to check if a mob (and perhaps of a custom named mob) has x amount of health left. Example: Im making a skeleton boss, and when he hits half health, I want him to summon some "skeleton warriors" to assist him in battle. Any ideas?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to detect a mobs health, on Java 1.17](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/387385/how-to-detect-a-mobs-health-on-java-1-17)

Comment: Closing an older question as a duplicate of a newer question because this one has an outdated answer.

Comment: In that case I suggest a merge, so we can combine answers pertaining to different versions (if, in the future, we'll have tagged answers for versions, as has been discussed on Meta, this would be a great use for it).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like **this**.

`/testfor @e[x,y,z,r,type=Skeleton] {Health:10s}`

If you want the name in it do this. (Correct me if I'm wrong.)

`/testfor @e[x,y,z,r,type=Skeleton,name=Jimmy] {Health:10s}`

[How To Check A Mobs Health](http://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/minecraft-discussion/redstone-discussion-and/2239176-how-to-check-mobs-health)

Comment: Awesome. Sorry, but do what does the "s" stand for in {Health:10s}? Half hearts? Whole hearts?

Comment: It is whole health (as in, 0-10 hearts). I'm assuming if you wanted health you could use 0.5

Comment: @SMILIECHICKEN The "s" is a tag-type declaration for NBT data. It causes a whole number between -32768 and 32767 to have the [short datatype](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_%28computer_science%29#Short_integer). There's handful of declarations: `byte:1b`, `byte:true`, `byte:false`, `short:1s`, `integer:1`, `long:1l`, `float:1.0f`, `double:1.0`, `double:1.0d`, `IntArray:[1,2,3]`, `List:[]`, `Compound:{}`, `string:none of the previous declarations` `string:"quotes, allowing commas as values"`. "true/false" are byte values of 1 and 0 respectively.

Comment: @SMILIECHICKEN You can find a list of all NBT datatypes [here](http://minecraft.gamepedia.com/NBT_format), noting that there is no declaration available for `ByteArray`. This means you cannot create or detect a byte array using commands and would need a third-party editor to create one.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can test for a mob with a specific amount of health and a custom name.

---

For example:

```
/testfor @e[x,y,z,r,type=Creeper,name=George] {Health:10s}
```

would test for a creeper within a radius of the target coordinates named George with 10 health. This should be placed on a loop to continually test the parameters.

Also, note that the {Health:10s} tag is separate from the entity tags. That is because health can only be stored in an NBT tag for mobs. As an added note, health can only be tested for exact values, not ranges.

[(Source)](http://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/minecraft-discussion/redstone-discussion-and/2239176-how-to-check-mobs-health)